# Maintaining different localized versions of interface NIB files

Tags: localization, interface-builder, nib, ios5, xcode4.2

I'm learning the basics steps to internationalize an app and I have a question about localizing interface NIB files... I've seen that in Xcode you can click on a AppViewController.xib interface file and click on the *+* in the Localization section of the inspector window to add another language along with the default English one (I add Italian for example)... This allows me to translate the interface in Italian... but then how do you maintain future evolution of the App? If you need to add a button, for example, you have to add it *by hand* to all the localized versions of your interface NIB file? Documentation says also

> Objects in a nib file typically have connections between them that should not be broken. Make sure you lock all connections before handing your nibs off to translation. For information on how to lock down your nib file, see “Localization” in Interface Builder User Guide.

Can you explain me this concept? I've seen the Localization Locking section within the inspector which allows you to lock *Properties*, *Localizable Properties* or *Un-localizable Properties*, but I don't understand very well what it does.

So, to sum up a bit, I'd like you to suggest me what is the workflow to design localized versions of your interface and maintain the multiple NIB files when the interface evolves.

EDIT: any idea and/or link that can help me?

Answer (score 0):

iLocalize provides an easy way of localising an app and updating translated nibs. If you'd rather use `ibtool`, `--localize-incremental`, which will handle the changes in a nib and copy them to the translated nibs, is explained well [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8424453/1111022).

Alternatively, you could use `NSLocalizedString`s and one nib which is useful in some instances. Set each control's title in code and you need only worry about making the controls wide enough for the longest translation.