# How do I apply changes to a localized XIB that's been "tweaked" already?

Tags: xcode, xcode4, localization, xib, ibtool

Say I modify the default XIB (in en.lproj) by adding a button or something similar.

I need to apply these changes to other existing localized versions of the XIB (e.g. es.lproj, ja.lproj).

If I rewrite the XIB then I clearly lose any tweaks made to the localized XIB. For instance, say I reduced the font size on a button in the XIB for ja.lproj.

E.g. this overwrites:

> ibtool --strings-file
>   ja.strings
>   en.lproj/any.xib --write
>   ja.lproj/any.xib

How can I effectively merge changes between XIBs? Is it possible?

Do I have to just suck it up and redo the tweaks in localized XIBs any time I make a change in the "root" or default XIB?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `--incremental-file` option? It detects the changes that you've made between two versions of a source language xib and applies them to a translated xib, bringing them back in sync. In my understanding (I haven't verified this), anything that hasn't changed is left untouched, so I expect that any tweaks to the translated xib that aren't affected by a change are left in.

See [this other Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8401630/how-does-incremental-localization-work/8424453#8424453) for more detail on this ibtool option.